# Should I review a Paper of NonSci journal

Tags: review-articles

I am researcher in computer science in India. Very recently I got an email stating that my work is great and they want me to review research papers.

I check about the journal. It is not SCI indexed journal (and it is a paid journal). Now I am not sure should I review a paper from such kind of journal. Will it be bad for my reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They want your free labor. I doubt that there is a real person at the journal who thinks your work is great. I would say no, without even bothering to answer this spam request.

If they actually sent you a paper and it looked really interesting to you and worth your time, then you could consider saying yes.

Neither answer will affect your reputation in any significant way.

Comment: Hmmm. Actually _all_ journals want the free labor of reviewers. A few can "pay" by sending an occasional book, though.

Comment: @Buffy True. But when you referee for respectable journals you are paid several ways: early looks at relevant papers, items in your annual faculty report, general professional advancement.

Comment: You don't only get an early look, but you set aside an afternoon to read the manuscript *thoroughly*. :-)  Feels great afterwards. We do that far too rarely.